# Javascript Arrow function expression to regular function expression

Tags: javascript

How do you convert the following arrow function expression to a regular one?

```
rootRef.on('child_removed', snapshot => {
    console.log('Child(s) removed');
    B4A.CallSub('onchild_removed',true,"Child Added");

});
```

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: By "convert", what do you mean? Convert them programmatically or by hand?

Comment: Change `snapshot =>` to `function(snapshot)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to convert a arrow function to a regular function. A ["regular" function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) syntax is:

```
function name(param) {
    // do the following scripts:
    document.body.innerHTML = param;
}
```

So, if you want to convert your arrow function to a default one, you could do something like this:

```
rootRef.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
    console.log('Child(s) removed');
    B4A.CallSub('onchild_removed',true,"Child Added");

});
```